# Execution does not go out of the loop in ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm, qemu

I want to print in ARM assembly language a given number in decimal in hexadecimal. I'm doing the function that does the conversion and the printing. So far the conversion works but the printing not at all.

It does only print a char at a time and it's not at all what I want, I want a special format of output such that I have 0x and 8 digits.

I wrote a function *printf* using the given function I had, called *_writec* that is working but only printing a char at a time. So I wrote a loop until I get the end of string function but here it seems that it doesn't care.

I've followed the execution step-by-step using gdb and it suddenly crash for no appearing reason. When r0 contain 0 it should go to *.end* according to my *beq* but it does not.

ARM Code:

```
.global _print_hex
_print_hex:

push {lr}
@According to .c algorithm : r0 = dec; r1 = quotient; 
@ r2 = temp; r3 = i ; r4 = j 

mov fp, sp
sub sp, sp, #100 @ 100 times size of char
mov r1, r0
mov r3, #0

_while:
   cmp r1, #0
   bne _computing

   ldr r0, =.hex_0x
   bl _printf

   mov r4, #8
_for:
   cmp r4, #0
   bge _printing

   ldr r0, =.endline
   bl _printf

   mov sp, fp
   pop {pc}

_computing:
   and r2, r1, #0xF
   cmp r2, #10
   blt .temp_less_10
   add r2, #7
   .temp_less_10:
   add r2, #48
   strb r2, [sp, r3]
   add r3, #1
   lsr r1, #4
   b _while 

_printing:
   ldrb r0, [sp,r4]
   bl _writec
   sub r4, #1
   b _for

_printf:
   push {r0, r1, r2, r3, lr}
   mov r1, r0
   mov r2, #0
.loop:
   ldrb r0, [r1,r2]
   cmp r0, #0
   beq .end
   bl _writec
   add r2, #1
    b .loop

.end:
   pop {r0, r1, r2, r3, lr}
   bx lr

.hex_0x:
   .asciz "0x"
   .align 4

.endline:
   .asciz "\n"
   .align 4
```

C code (that I tried to translate):

```
 void dec_to_hex(int dec){
       int quotient, i, temp;
       char hex[100];
       quotient = dec;
       i = 0;

    while (quotient != 0){
        temp = quotient % 16;
        if (temp < 10){
            temp += 48; // it goes in the ascii table between 48 and 57 that correspond to [0..9]
        } else {
            temp += 55; //it goes in the first cap letters from 65 to 70 [A..F]
        }
        hex[i]=(char)temp;
        i++;
        quotient /= 16;
    }
    printf("0x");
    for(int j=i; j>=0; j--){
        printf("%c", hex[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Here is the code of _writec :

```
/*
 * Sends a character to the terminal through UART0
 * The character is given in r0.
 * IF the TX FIFO is full, this function awaits
 * until there is room to send the given character.
*/
    .align 2
.global _writec
    .type _writec,%function
    .func _writec,_writec
_writec:
    push {r0,r1,r2,r3,lr}
    mov r1, r0
    mov r3, #1
    lsl r3, #5      // TXFF = (1<<5)

    ldr r0,[pc]
    b .TXWAIT
    .word UART0
.TXWAIT:
    ldr r2, [r0,#0x18]      // flags at offset 0x18
    and r2, r2, r3      // TX FIFO Full set, so wait
    cmp r2,#0
    bne .TXWAIT
    strb r1, [r0,#0x00]      // TX at offset 0x00
    pop {r0,r1,r2,r3,pc}
    .size   _writec, .-_writec
    .endfunc
```

So in ARM when debugging it crashed at my first call of `_printf` and when I comment all the call to `_printf` it does print the result but not as the desired format. I only got the hex value.

Comment: You did not show `_writec` ... it may very well be altering `r4`. Also, you did not show gdb transcript illustrating `beq` not branching and the crash itself.

Comment: you're right but I didn't write ```_writec```. r4 is in fact not altered I took too much precaution it's useless.

Comment: Your code seems fine and works fine except for the fact that your computing loop does not always produce 8 digits since it terminates as soon as `r1` becomes zero. Instead check that `r3` becomes `8` (and as an optimization you could then use that to count down for printing).